# Absolute Div is moving down when the page height dynamically increases

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a problem with my pop-up. When the page height increases vertically, the pop up div also moves vertically down. I have two divs. One is a blanket which is a black transparent layer and the other is the pop-up which is overlaid on top of it.

CSS:

```
#blanket {
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.65;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9001;
 /*above nine thousand*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#validationPopup {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 5px solid #68ad0e;
    width: 300px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    z-index: 9002;
 /*above nine thousand*/;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="validationPopup" style="display:none;">
    </br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;color:#060;" onclick="popup('validationPopup')">
        <div align="right">close[X]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </a>
    <br>
    <div id="validationMessage" align="center"></div>
</div>
```

I want the pop-up to be in the middle of the window even when the page height increases dynamically.

**Edit 1**: I tried `position: absolute` but it's still not working.

```
**I also want the Div to be populated in center of the browser (not center to the total height)**
```

Comment: Use `position: absolute` rather than `position: fixed`.

Comment: @putvande : he said, he tried even absolute but not working

Comment: @putvande:I have used it but the result is same. . .

Comment: Yeah fair enough. You can also do it with `fixed` but you just need to set the right positions (`left`, `top`, `margin`). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set `left` and `top` both to `50%` and add a minus margin of half the popup size:

```
#validationPopup {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border:5px solid #68ad0e;
    width:300px;
    height:125px;
    margin-top:-62px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    z-index: 9002;
}
```

The background needs `height:100%`:

```
#blanket {
    /* ... */
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc47x/1/)

Comment: now the DIV will populate into center of the page. But he actually wants to display it in center of the browser not center to the total height

Comment: Ah. That was added after I posted my answer.

Comment: background  of the div is not coming. . .its 100% transparent

Comment: after you changed it to position:fixed, the pop-up div is not appearing now. . .

Comment: Set background to height 100%

Comment: @putvande : what is the solution for background color ? he said it is not coming...

Comment: @putvande : fiddle example is not showing background of validationPopup div.

Comment: @putvande: In fiddle,The Background of the Popup Div is transparent.